# Blender - non-weighted tangents in graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor, bezier-curves

I know this feature is not implemented in Blender but it's really annoying when animating primarily in Graph Editor without non-weighted tangents. Are there any scripts or plugins that give a similar effect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an explanation or link as to what non-weighted tangents are, and / or how they are used in maya?

Comment: Hi, this is the link to explanation images :) thank you for your time https://imgur.com/a/ZGqRh